# Android ScrollView Scroll to Bottom

Tags: android, android-scrollview

The `ScrollView` in Android is really confusing. I'm working on an app that adds a fragment of text to a `TextView` inside the `ScrollView`, and I want it to scroll to the bottom of the `ScrollView`.

I've tried these ways:

`Scroll1.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);`

`Scroll1.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());`

`Scroll1.scrollTo(0, Scroll1.getY() + Scroll1.getHeight());`

NOTE: 
1. Scroll1 is the `ScrollView` I used. 2. The first two methods can't scroll to the bottom. The last just doesn't work.

How can I achieve this? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it may helps if I know your problem:
paste it in scroll view in xml

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

OR

in java activity

```
scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code once you want to update the scrollview:

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() {
         scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollView may not scroll to bottom in onCreate until you give some time to the view to inflate fully.

**So to make it scroll...**

```
mScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                View lastChild = mScrollView.getChildAt(mScrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
                int bottom = lastChild.getBottom() + mScrollView.getPaddingBottom();
                int sy = mScrollView.getScrollY();
                int sh = mScrollView.getHeight();
                int delta = bottom - (sy + sh);

                mScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, delta);
            }
        },1000);
```

You can **also** use `scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);` in run()

I combinde this from a lot of answers. It finally helped me.