# SoftKeyboard override editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

I have scrollview with some elements, and one of them - edit text, near the bottom of layout.
when this editText request focus by click - soft keyboard is opened and override that editText fild, so user cant see what he typing...

any ideas why it happen and how to fix it?

here is my code manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".acitivity.TransferActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_transfer"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>
```

here is activity xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_transfer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/container_transfer_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_transfer" />


</LinearLayout>
```

here is fragment xml:

```
 <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/transfer_scroller"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/blue_500"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                        //some code here
               </LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                        //some code here
               </LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_transfer_p1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray_400"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_main_2" >
                        </EditText>
               </LinearLayout>
               </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Maybe you set `android:windowTranslucentStatus=true` for your `Activity` in your styles.xml. Please add your styles.xml.

Comment: try with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest

Comment: have a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft  -- you may need to add (adjustUnspecified)

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297810/android-scrollview-scroll-to-bottom/32298328#32298328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Glad to help you...Happy Coding :)

Comment: Work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this to your manifest file:**

```
<activity
   android:name="com.android.test.ActivityName"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_transfer_p1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_400"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_main_2" />
```

and set ScrollView height to `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

simply go to manifest and write this code

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustNothing"

like this suppose your activity namecom.something.Activity

```
       <activity  android:name="com.something.Activity"

         android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustNothing"
        ></activity>
```

it will adjust and your textview position will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

In your ScrollView add which lets you to scroll and type in edittext efficiently:

```
android:fillViewport="true
```